# Error creating a record XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I am trying to create an annotation using js: XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create.

I get a systax error all the time but I cannot find the problem...

here is my code

```
var id = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
        var nam = parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getEntityName();

        var entity = {};

        entity.subject = "title";
        entity.notetext = "description";
        entity.objectid = {
            id: id,
            logicalname: nam
        };



        XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create(
        entity,
        "annotation",
        function (result) {
            alert("OK");
        },
        function (error) {
            //Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message, null);
            alert("KO: " + error.message);
        },
        false
        );
```

I get a "Syntax error"
anyone knows where is the problem??

thanks a lot

Comment: What version of Dynamics 365 are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you use Webapi, if you are on crm 2016 or higer version better go with Webapi.
Below is code snippet for webapi which creates noted.

```
var entity = {};
entity.subject = "Test from webapi";
entity.notetext = "just add some text";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/annotations", false);
req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 204) {
            var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
            var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
            var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
            var newEntityId = matches[1];
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
    }
};
req.send(JSON.stringify(entity));
```

And now with XrmserviceToolkit

```
var entity = {};
entity.Subject = "Test from webapi 1234";
entity.NoteText = "just add some text 1234";

XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create(entity, "AnnotationSet", function(result) {
    var newEntityId = result.AnnotationId;
}, function(error) {
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
}, false);
```

Also what is the issue with your code?
If you look my code above for XrmserviceToolkit, You need to give Entity name as `AnnotationSet`. Also you do not need Id because CRM will create Id once a record is created.

Comment: thanks for your answer... finally I have used the XrmserviceToolkit.soap and works fine... I will try the web api too. by the way I do not understand why annotation + SET... the soap works fine with just "annotation"

Comment: if you look at webapi code snippet it uses Entity Schema name +s 
and in similar way when using Rest it uses Entity schema name + Set